# Error on getting debug port :: Unable to authenticate on RDS server using current security information. (Adobe's ColdFusion extension)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, coldfusion, adobe

I installed [Adobe's ColdFusion extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=com-adobe-coldfusion.adobe-cfml-lsp&ssr=false#overview). I added local server (127.0.0.1:80), created workspace and now I want to debug my project. I opened some cfml file, I go to "Run and Debug" tab and click "Run and Debug" button. I get the following error messages:

> Debugger Stopped

> Error on getting debug port :: Unable to authenticate on RDS server using current security information.

**What do I need to do to be able to debug my code?**

*Additional stuff:*

Debugging works perfectly fine in Eclipse's CF Builder. In CF Administrator debug port is set to default - 5005. I don't really know what that RDS (Remote Development Service) is but I don't remember having to set that up for Eclipse's CFB (even if I did). Do I have to have RDS to be able to debug?

The most useful piece of documentation from Adobe I was able to find is located here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/sg/coldfusion/coldfusion-builder-extension-for-visual-studio-code/debug-applications.html

Quote:

> ### Run and debug in VS Code
>
> If you have not configured running and debugging, then VS Code
> displays the Run start view.
>
> Run and Debug is a custom debug option provided by VS Code. If you
> click Create a JSON launch file and follow the prompts, you can
> associate your file with "CFML Debug" profile and then use it to run
> the debugger.
>
> CFML debug has overridden VS Code’s default debug and run commands.
> So, debugger can be started without creating json file.

But even if I create debugger launch json file and then click green debug triangle I still get the same error message.

---

## Update

I got RDS enabled and was able to successfully connect:

[image]

[image]

I go to "Run and Debug" section of vscode, select "CFML Debug" configuration from dropdown to create debug config, click on a green triangle and get the following error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')

[image]

I had a clean reinstall of vscode and Adobe's ColdFusion extension is only one I have installed:

[image]

Small edit/update:

I am also able to control CF server (stop/start/restart) from within vscode:

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Question:

What do I need to do to fix "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'document')" error?

Comment: [Somewhat relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555701/how-to-setup-visual-studio-code-for-running-and-debugging-coldfusion-code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable RDS in CF administrator in Security section. [image]
You can choose the RDS password or no authentication as per your preferences. Then, you would need to provide the authentication information in VSCode while adding the Server.
You can find more detail about the VSCode extension including debugger in this video - https://youtu.be/90sOeP48TS0?t=2630

Comment: Your answer lead me in the right direction and I was able to make some progress. Thank you. However, I still get, now, a different error message. (I still haven't found a complete guide or a video where somebody sets up and runs a debugger, with detailed instructions of each step).

Comment: Were you able to run the CFM from your vscode editor?

Comment: If you mean start/stop CF server then yes, I was able to do that from within vscode. I made a small update about that to my question.

Comment: The video link I shared has a demo related to how you can get a CFM to execute in browser right from VSCode editor by right-click on file and choosing Run as ColdFusion Application. Once you are able to do so, debugging is also done in the same way by choosing 'Debug as ColdFusion Application' in the same right-click menu.

Comment: I did not see that part of video. Thank you. I will research this.

Comment: I managed to run a debugger! Thank you! I am getting a different error now when trying to see contents of variables, but that's a different problem now :) .

Comment: You are welcome! I would request you to modify the rating in marketplace if possible. It will help spread good word about the extension. 
For variables, try enabling Request Debugging Output in your CF Admin. Then, the variable contents should also be visible.

Comment: FYI, I enabled "Enable Request Debugging Output" checkbox in CF Admin, I don't get error message anymore, but when I try to expend objects (in "Variables" or "Watch" windows) it's just spinning and not expending anything. But's that a different question at this point. I may ask another question about it if I won't figure this out.